# Do sets of permutations uniquely correspond to groups?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have two (distinct) sets of permutations $S_1$ and $S_2$ which both form a group under composition.

Could it be the case that the two groups are isomorphic even though sets contain different permutations?

Comment: The sets $\{1, (1\,2)\}$ and $\{1, (1\,3)\}$ are both subgroups of $S_3$ (the symmetric group containing permutations of 3 elements). They both are isomorphic to the cyclic group of size two but have different permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. Consider $\{1,(1\,2)\}$ and $\{1,(1\, 3)\}$ and $\{1,(1\,2)(3\,4)\}$ (as subsets of the symmetric group on $4$ numbers.